# Create include dir for CMake install target

Tags: cmake

I'm am trying to create an install target for a shared lib that uses links to a interface lib. I would like to have create a lib folder that contains the lib and an include folder that contains the necessary headers (public ones of both the shared and interface lib).

First the interface lib:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE PUBLIC_HDRS include/*.h)

add_library(MyLib INTERFACE ${PUBLIC_HDRS})
target_include_directories(MyLib INTERFACE include)
```

Then the shared lib:

```
set(PUBLIC_INCLUDE include)
set(PRIVATE_INCLUDE src)
set(SRC src)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS ${SRC}/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE PUB_HDRS ${PUBLIC_INCLUDE}/*.h)
file(GLOB_RECURSE PRIV_HDRS ${PRIVATE_INCLUDE}/*.h)

add_library(MySharedLib SHARED ${SRCS} ${PUB_HDRS} ${PRIV_HDRS})                                         
target_include_directories(MySharedLib PRIVATE ${PRIVATE_INCLUDE} 
                                       PUBLIC ${PUBLIC_INCLUDE})

target_link_libraries(MySharedLib PUBLIC MyLib)

target_sources(MySharedLib PUBLIC "${PUB_HDRS}")
get_target_property(MYLIB_PUBLIC_HEADERS MySharedLib INTERFACE_SOURCES)
set_target_properties(MySharedLib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "${MYLIB_PUBLIC_HEADERS}")
install(TARGETS MySharedLib 
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include)
```

However the INTERFACE_SOURCES seem to only contain the headers of the shared lib and not the ones of the interface lib. Even after adding to the interface lib:

```
target_sources(MyLib PUBLIC "${PUBLIC_HDRS}")
```

How can I fix this? Is there an easier way to do this? I feels a bit strange I have to set the `target_sources` since these are also specified in the `target_include_directories`.

Comment: Why not to specify PUBLIC_HEADER property for `MyLib` target itself, and install that target? (In CMake INTERFACE libraries could be installed too).

Comment: By using `get_target_property(... MySharedLib)` you cannot extract properties, which are set for target `MyLib`, The command `target_link_libraries(MySharedLib PUBLIC MyLib)` actually propagates INTERFACE properties of `MyLib` target to `MySharedLib`. But that propagation is performed only at the **end** of the configuration process, not when `get_target_property` is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That makes sense. I can set the PUBLIC_HEADER property for `MyLib` but how would I have it installed in a location specified by the `MySharedLib`? I would like to install all headers needed by `MySharedLib` in MySharedLib/include without specifying this explicitly in `Mylib`.

Comment: "I would like to install all headers needed by `MySharedLib` in `MySharedLib/include` without specifying this explicitly in `Mylib`." - Installation directory is not a part of the target. So you are free to `install(TARGET MyLib ...)` in the `MySharedLib/CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Ah yes, of course! Didn't realise that. Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake's INTERFACE library target behaves like a "normal" library target in many ways. Among other things, it is allowed to specify PUBLIC_HEADER property for an INTERFACE target and even install that target:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE PUBLIC_HDRS include/*.h)

add_library(MyLib INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(MyLib INTERFACE include)
set_property(TARGET MyLib PROPERTY PUBLIC_HEADER ${PUBLIC_HDRS})
install(TARGETS MyLib PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include)
```

Installation of a target doesn't need to be specified in the same `CMakeLists.txt` which creates that target. So you may install both targets `MySharedLib` and `MyLib` with the single command in the `MySharedLib/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
install(TARGETS MySharedLib MyLib
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include)
```

That way you will need to specify the layout for installed artifacts only once.

---

Your approach with using `get_target_property` for extract properties, derived by target `MySharedLib` from the target `MyLib` doesn't work.

While call

```
target_link_libraries(MySharedLib PUBLIC MyLib)
```

propagates interface properties of `MyLib` target to `MySharedLib`, this propagation is performed only **at the end of the configuration process**.
But `get_target_property` reads only *current* value of the property.